# how to log process md files with junit?

Tags: concordion

I work on a project using concordion, maven and junit. There are a lot's of md files which are processed but the logs do not contain the name of the processed md file. So it is hard to link logs lines to executed tests.

How is it possible to log the name of processed md file ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the details logged in the output specification, take a look at the [echo command](https://concordion.org/instrumenting/java/markdown/#echo-command) (or the [embed extension](https://github.com/concordion/concordion-embed-extension/blob/master/README.md) if you want to alter the HTML formatting).

If you just want it logged to a log file, you'll need to look at a logging framework (eg. slf4j/logback). The [logback extension](https://github.com/concordion/concordion-logback-extension/blob/master/README.md) can make the log accessible from the concordion output specification.

Comment: Ok thanks i will looked at the llinks but i thought that i can log in java the name of the processed md file ...